# Disable cascading from dependant to owner

Tags: grails, grails-orm, cascade

I have a problem with saves cascading to the owner object from the dependant (Book to Library, in this case).

I have two domains like so:

```
Library {
  String name

  static hasMany = [ books: Book]
}

Book {
  static belongsTo = [ library: Library]
}
```

And I access them restfully.

Now lets say there are two libraries:

- id: 1, name: library1
- id: 2, name: library2

And I have a book that belongs to library-1. I get it like so:

```
GET /book/1
response: {
  id: 1,
  library: {
    id: 1,
    name: "library1"
  }
}
```

And then someone updates the book record, assigning it to a different library

```
PUT /book/1
request body: {
  id: 1,
  library: {
    id: 2,
    name: "library1"
  }
}
```

And then it will rename the library with id: 2 to name "library1".

- id: 1, name: library1
- id: 2, name: library1

I expect it to just get the id of the library from the request, and update the library_id field of the book record.

What should I do?

Comment: Don't post the name of the library in the update request. Just include the id. Otherwise you will have to write your own implementation(s) to take care of this situation.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore Well I am just writing the API. I cannot control the API users to do it one way or another, I have to handle it manually.

Does it write somewhere that the solution to this has to be implemented on the controller-side, or ?

Comment: Yes, you will have to implement your own Controller(s) to handle this. I would recommend you look at what the existing scaffolding creates and modify it to suit your needs. Before you write any further code you would be best off reading the Grails documentation (yes I know there is a lot, but it will save you a lot of work too).

Comment: @JoshuaMoore just add a response then so I can accept and close this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to modify the default behavior of the REST functionality within Grails scaffolding you need to implement your own controller(s) to handle this.

I would recommend you look at what the existing scaffolding creates and modify it to suit your needs. Before you write any further code you would be best off reading the [Grails documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html) (yes I know there is a lot, but it will save you a lot of work too).